# How to interpret the notation?

Tags: functional-analysis

im asked to do this exercise: [image]

Im quite unsure what the notation $(Tx)_i$ means and is $T$ a bounded linear operator or a matrix?

Comment: "*Is $T$ a bounded linear operator or a matrix?*"  It is both.  It is whichever you want it to be at the time in order to be convenient for whatever use you have for it.  Linear operators can be described with matrices.  Matrices describe linear operators.  They may formally be different objects, but it is like saying that the real number $2$ and the natural number $2$ are formally different objects.  We can still switch between them freely at will.

Comment: "What the notation $(Tx)_i$ means.  Well, $Tx$ is the result of the linear operator applied to $x$.  That result will itself be a vector.  $(Tx)_i$ is the $i$'th entry of the vector $(Tx)$.

Comment: oh right, so i dont need to know the operator T explicitly to complete the exercise ?

Comment: $(Tx)_i$ is the $i$'th coordinate of $Tx$. Similarly to $x_i$ being the $i$'th coordinate of $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a hint for the first equality, and what is intended that you do:

$$(Tx)_i=(\textstyle\sum_{j=1}^dT(x_je_j))_i=(\sum_{j=1}^d x_jT(e_j))_i=\sum_{j=1}^d x_j(T(e_j))_i=\sum_{j=1}^d x_j(T(e_j)|e_i)$$

Your main perspective is to think of $T$ as a linear operator first and foremost; the result of the exercise is that one can henceforth think of $T$ as a matrix via the matrix elements.

Let me know if you need more hints.

Comment: thanks i get it now!